# Reading the Facebook Graph API - Access token error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I want to do is get basic information about a FB Page (total page likes, posts posted by the page). Using the Facebook Javascript SDK I am running into problems.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({
            appId: '12345', //My app id 
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.5'
        });

        /* make the API call */
        FB.api(
            "/128155725517",
            'GET',
            // {"fields":"id,name"},
            function(response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
        );
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And the response I get is:

```
/**/ FB.__globalCallbacks.f1084b047c({"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"HUcIot7YeoH"}});
```

My question is this: Can I request from the Graph API WITHOUT a user access token? Do they have to log in to get an access token for me to read info from the Graph API? Can I create a token that will always work, no matter if the website visitor is logged into FB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without login, you can only use an "App Access Token". It is just a combination of App ID and App Secret - but you should never use it in client code, of course. If the Page is restricted by age or location, you need to use a User Token or Page Token.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you @luschn - much appreciated. I will look into App Access Tokens. Have a great day!